# outdoor sump electrical

Tags: wiring, receptacle, gfci, sump-pump

I have a sump pit at the bottom of some outdoor basement steps that I need to get an outlet run to.

I'm going to put the dedicated receptacle on the outside cement wall ... so drill through the concrete and then run from my junction box (in the basement), 12/2 down to the hole on a secured pressure treated 2x4 - once at the hole the Romex will go through a piece of EMT through the wall, elbow down or up to where the receptacle is needed outside.

Anyone see any issue?

Comment: Romex doesn't work outdoors, not even in conduit.  UF does, but 12/2 UF is too large for 1/2" conduit.  If the conduit is continuous from outdoors to the outlet box, put a junction box *on the inside* of the building, and run THHN wires through the conduit.  Also that junction box is a good place to put the GFCI protector.  (better to have it not outdoors, weather is hard on them).

Comment: but I think it can go directly into the back of the box?

Comment: that's a wobbler, most people say "yes", but you can't travel any distance outdoors in EMT with it. When I say "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't work, it'll get soaked, leak current and trip GFCIs.

Comment: ok ok - so I can do 12/2 NM to the junction box (already done) and then THNN 12 from the junction to the outlet via EMT? better ?

Comment: yeah, most people will pass that, but like I say if the Romex actually gets wet it may cause problems.

Comment: Yeah but in this case it shouldn’t be an issue since the Romex is inside and then I transition to 12g Thnn